# Perl service status codes from Win32::Service module GetStatus() call do not match that of Services.msc applet

Tags: windows, perl, winapi, service

I have been trying to write a Perl script that would check the service status of Remote Servers. I am using the [Win32::Service](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32%3a%3aService) module to accomplish my goal.

I find that the for some services value returned by `Win32::Service::GetStatus` `CurrentStatus` is not exactly the same as observed from services.msc applet.

Here is the piece of script I am using along with both outputs from script and `servics.msc`.

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Win32;
use Win32::Service;
use strict;
use warnings;

my %statcodeHash = (     '1' => 'stopped.',
                     '2' => 'start pending.',
                     '3' => 'stop pending.',
                     '4' => 'running.',
                     '5' => 'continue pending.',
                     '6' => 'pause pending.',
                     '7' => 'paused.'            );


my @serviceNames = qw(NNMAction RpcEptMapper smstsmgr SNMPTRAP);

foreach my $serv (@serviceNames)
{   my %status;
    my $ret = Win32::Service::GetStatus('nnmi.hclt.corp.hcl.in', $serv, \%status);
    if ($ret)
    {   print "success\t$statcodeHash{$status{CurrentState}}\t$serv\n";
    }
    else
    {       print Win32::FormatMessage(Win32::GetLastError()), "\n";
    }
}
```

*OUTPUT from Script*

```
D:\AVI MEHENWAL\PERL\SCRIPTS\PROJECTS\Serve Management>perl -w perl_RemoteServiceStatus.pl
success stopped.        NNMAction
success running.        RpcEptMapper
success stopped.        smstsmgr
success stopped.        SNMPTRAP
```

*OUTPUT from Services.msc*

```
Name       Descrition   Status   StartupType  LogOnAs
NNMAction  bla bla bla  Started  Manual       LocalSystem
```

Can anyone suggest me what approach should I follow to achieve my goal, Is my method wrong or there is something I am missing from Perl module point of view?

Comment: Here is the piece of script I am using along with both outputs from script and servics.msc

Comment: use Win32::Service;
my @serviceName = (     'NNMAction',
                        'RpcEptMapper',
                        'smstsmgr',
                        'SNMPTRAP'      );
foreach $serv (@serviceName)
{ Win32::Service::GetStatus('nnmi.hclt.corp.hcl.in' , $serv , \%status);
      print "$status{CurrentState} $serv \n";
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Updated

I noticed that `nnmi.hclt.corp.hcl.in` seems to be a domain name rather than a Windows style machine name. First, find out the IP address corresponding to `nnmi.hclt.corp.hcl.in`. Let's say it is `x.x.x.x`.

Now, run `nbtstat -A x.x.x.x`. That should tell you the name of the machine. Let's say it is `NNMI`. Then, you should specify that in the `my $remote` line below, replacing `MYREMOTE` with `NNMI`, and try again.

I am assuming you have the correct privileges etc. If you get an authorization related error, I am afraid I cannot help you, but you can ask on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) to find out what you need to do so as to be able to query services on a remote machine in the domain.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Win32;
use Win32::Service;

my %status_codes = reverse (
    SERVICE_STOPPED          => 0x00000001,
    SERVICE_START_PENDING    => 0x00000002,
    SERVICE_STOP_PENDING     => 0x00000003,
    SERVICE_RUNNING          => 0x00000004,
    SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING => 0x00000005,
    SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING    => 0x00000006,
    SERVICE_PAUSED           => 0x00000007,
);

my $remote = '\\\\MYREMOTE';

my @services = qw(Fax ClipSrv AcrSch2Svc);

foreach my $svc (@services) {
    my %status;
    my $ret = Win32::Service::GetStatus($remote, $svc, \%status);

    if ($ret) {
        printf(
            "success\t%s\t%s\n",
            $status_codes{ $status{CurrentState} },
            $svc
        );
    }
    else
    {
        warn sprintf(
            "failed to get '%s' status: %s\n",
            $svc,
            Win32::FormatMessage(Win32::GetLastError())
        );
    }
}
```

For reference, the [`SERVICE_STATUS` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Sinan for your better improved code with error handling. I really like your code :-)

Comment: But I am still facing same problem with this code. Script output doesnt match output from Services.msc    I am updatng my problem and question for same. Please help

Comment: Thanks again Sinan ! This thing worked for systems which are NOT in any domain. Is it possible that you can tell me how to access services for computers in domain via Perl. Thanks a lot

Comment: The user under which you are running the program have to have the necessary credentials/authorization. AFAIK, that's a sysadmin issue, independently of Perl. What happens if you start the cmd.exe shell in which you are running the program with "Run As ..."?

Comment: The user I am working with is a part windows administrator group and is a part of my organizations domain.
Script is not working for my desktop in domain for remote servers !!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986236/how-to-query-for-service-status-in-windows-servers-under-some-domain-via-perl